# bold \angstrom (perhaps in conjunction with siunitx)?

Tags: math-mode, siunitx, bold

How can I get a bold `\angstrom` (perhaps in conjunction with `siunitx`)?

```
\mathbf{(\si{\angstrom})}
```

or

```
\bm{(\si{\angstrom})}
```

or

```
\boldmath{(\si{\angstrom})}
```

does not work.

An example- I want the following in a table's column heading:

```
\multicolumn{4}{c}{$\bm{a}${\bfseries (\SI{}{\angstrom})}}
```

The above is not printing the angstrom symbol at all. The following does not make the angstrom bold.

```
\multicolumn{4}{c}{$\boldmath{(\SI{}{\angstrom})}$}
```

Though the following works in normal text.

```
{\bfseries (\SI{}{\angstrom})}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Like any other output, the standard setting for `siunitx` are to ignore any local formatting (the 'official' position on typesetting quantities as they are mathematical entities.) Most probably you want `detect-weight`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\sisetup{detect-weight}
\begin{document}

Some text \SI{10}{\angstrom}.

{\bfseries Some text \SI{10}{\angstrom}.}

\end{document}
```

Comment: The \bfseries is not working in math mode.

Comment: \multicolumn{4}{c}{$\bm{a}$ {\bfseries (\SI{}{\angstrom})}}. This one works. Thanks.